# Override \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Messages.php

Tags: magento, block, magento-1.7, extend

I am trying to override the messaging block in Magento but can't get it working.

I created needed files:

```
\app\etc\modules\Dss_Core.xml
\app\code\local\Dss\Core\Block\Messages.php
\app\code\local\Dss\Core\etc\config.xml
```

I have also created a custom admin login.phtml but one is showing correctly.
But when calling `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>` in login.phtml I don't see my message from my Dss_Core_Block_Messages.

I tried everything (changing files/clearing Magento cache) but can't get it working.

What do I need to change?

\app\etc\modules\Dss_Core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dss_Core>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Dss_Core>
    </modules>
</config>
```

\app\code\local\Dss\Core\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dss_Core>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Dss_Core>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
           <core>
              <rewrite>
                  <messages>
                      Dss_Core_Block_Messages
                  </messages>
              </rewrite>
           </core>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

\app\code\local\Dss\Core\Block\Messages.php

```
<?php
class DSS_Core_Block_Messages extends Mage_Core_Block_Messages
{
    public function getGroupedHtml()
    {
        return '<div class="alert alert-block" style="color: white;">custom dss errors</div>';
    }
}
```

\app\design\adminhtml\default\dss\template\login.phtml

```
<body id="page-login" onload="document.forms.loginForm.username.focus();">
    <div class="container login-container">
    <div id="messages"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
        <div class="login-box rounded">
            <form method="post" action="" id="loginForm">
                <div class="login-form">
                ...
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a typo in the class name `DSS_Core_Block_Messages` it should be `Dss_Core_Block_Messages` instead. You should also put your rewrite entry into one line `<messages>Dss_Core_Block_Messages</messages>`.

Comment: I have changed it to "Dss_Core_Block_Messages" and still nothing is showing on the login page. :(

Comment: I've enhanced my answer. Please fix your `config.xml` like recommended. I get a fatal error when my rewrite entry is formmated like yours. Beside them I've tested it and it has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem with extension of Mage_Core_Block_Messages was the compilation of magento: System->Tools->Compilation
The system simple did not load the php file, and was giving white screen of death